# How could I write/maintain a .txt file with name and time (scores list) sorted by increasing time?

Tags: python, file, sorting, text

This is what I have so far but it isn't working:

```
def InsertInsideTheTopPlayer (name, time):

  players = []
  with open("playersScores.txt") as f:
      for line in f:
          name, time = line.split(',')
          time = float(time)
          players.append((name, time))

  players.sort(key=lambda s: s[1])
  strtime = str(time)
  for name, time in players:
      f.write("%s\n" % (name+", "+ strtime))
```

`name` is a string and `time` is a float (rounded to 2 decimal places).

After some editing this is what I have:

```
def InsertInsideTheTopPlayer (name, time):

players = []
strtime = str(time)
players.append((name, strtime))
with open("playersScores.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, strtime = line.split(',')
        players.append((name, strtime))
f.close()  

players.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])

with open("playersScores.txt", "w") as f:
    for (name, strtime) in players:
        f.write("%s\n" % (name+","+ strtime))
f.close()
```

it works for 2 iterations then gives:

```
line 10, in <module>
players.append((name, strtime))
builtins.ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

it appears the sorting adds empty lines
Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this?

moving lines 8 & 9 into `if line != '\n':` is a workaround but I don't know how to stop the blank lines from happening.

```
if line != '\n':
            name, strtime = line.split(',')
            players.append((name, strtime))
```

Comment: `strtime` is being set to the `str(time)` of only the last value read, you have to convert to str for every iteration. just concatenate `str(time)` inside of your `f.write`

Comment: also, why is your function taking in `name and time` as arguments? doesn't look like it needs them

Comment: You need to tell us what "isn't working" means. What results are you expecting (example output)? What did you actually see?

Comment: the name and time arguments are so the functions knows the new name and time to add to the file. Right now it doesn't seem to be doing anything, no new time or name and the file doesn't sort.

Comment: Here's an example of the intended .txt file

(Previous):
    Joe, 31.44
    Kelly, 32.01
    Bob, 43.57

(New):
    Joe, 31.44
    Kelly, 32.01
    George, 33.53
    Bob, 43.57

Comment: but you then declare `name,time  = line,split(',')` which overwrites whatever you wanted `name` and `time` to be equal to whatever you read in the file...?

Comment: That escaped me, I will make that adjustment to my code now and test it.

Comment: Have you considered just keeping the scores in a proper Python data structure and then serializing that? You can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: I would consider that had the professor not specified a .txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

- You never add your new player to the list of players (you're passing in name and time, you probably need to start with one of `players = [(name, time)]` or have `players.append((name, time))` after the loop).
- You try to both read and write to the same file handle, you need to close `f` (using `f.close()`) and then re-open it for writing.
- You need to reset strtime inside the loop, otherwise you'll over-write the times of every player, with the time of the first player